# Sealing off a live wire

Tags: electrical

I bought a project house last year, and unfortunately it's turned out that one of the previous owners was a keen amateur electrician. Sadly his enthusiasm wasn't matched by competence or any sense of safety, and while replacing a ceiling I've discovered a loose live wire.

Obviously I'm going to get a professional in to deal with this, but in the meantime for peace of mind I'd like to make it a bit more safe.

Is putting the wires in a terminal block the best approach, and if so does it matter if the amp rating on that terminal block is higher than that of the wire that's leading into it?

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal block"?

Comment: Something like this

http://www.screwfix.com/p/chocbox/54936

Comment: The UK uses terminal blocks where the US uses wire nuts... I'd say that either, or a wrapping of electrical tape, would be a perfectly reasonable safety barrier.

Comment: I agree @Keshlam. is it also possible the wire is not hot just a spare or abandoned wire? +

Comment: Certainly possible (though the OP said "live")...  but even if disconnected it should be covered anyway in case someone reconnects it someday.

Comment: I am guessing that your use of "terminal blocks" puts you in the UK (or at least not the US). I do not know exactly how to find and reference the codes outside of the US. What does the your countrys home electrical code say? It should be covered in that regulation.

Comment: It's definitely live, discovered it was there in the first place by finding that out the hard way. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as a short-term solution, terminating the wire in a listed box is a good idea.

As a general statement, using something with a higher amp rating than necessary is fine.

If you could temporarily cut the power to the circuit, it would be even better, but I can imagine that other things are running...

Comment: Thanks - other things are running on the circuit so will terminate it until I've got a sparky in.